# Problems with RESTful return types

Tags: java, web-services, rest, types

I get this error while trying to call a RESTful webservice method:

`MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/xml, type=class [Ljava.lang.String;, genericType=class [Ljava.lang.String;`.

Here is the way I call the method from my code :

```
 try{
         PINClient pin=new PINClient();

         String[] resp = pin.tramo(String[].class, "1");

             out.println("pin"+resp[1]);

         }catch(Exception e){
             out.println(e);
         }
```

The answer is supposed to come as a text/xml, as I specified in the RESTful webservice, but I don't know what is causing this problem.
The webservice method:

```
@GET
    @Produces("text/xml")
    public String[] tramo(@QueryParam("tramo") String tramo) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        String[] pin=new String[300];
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.56.133:1521:TRACK", "oc","oc");
        Statement stmt=conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select IDT.ROWID, IDT.ID_ID, IDT.ID_PST_ID, IDT.ID_UM_ID,IDT.ID_POS, IDT.ID_PULSOS, IDT.ID_LANZAR, TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_COLOR_EXT, TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_SEC_MONT,TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_PRS_FAM,TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_SORTENES_FAM from IDT,TEL_FISKERNEL where IDT.ID_UM_ID =  TEL_FISKERNEL.TEL_PIN and ID_PST_ID="+tramo+" order by ID_POS" );
        int i=0;
        while(rs1.next()){
            pin[i]=rs1.getString("ID_UM_ID");
            i++;           
        }
        rs1.close();
        stmt.close();
        conexion.close();


        return pin;


    }
```

And the webservice client:

```
  public <T> T tramo(Class<T> responseType, String tramo) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    if (tramo != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("tramo", tramo);
    }
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(responseType);
}
```

Comment: @Produces("text/xml") but method returns String[] ?

Comment: Yes... it worked with a regular String, what should I do?

Comment: You should return String or some custom type which will be mapped to xml (it's called marshalling obj -> xml representation) I don't know if I will be mapped automatically, you need to check you REST API to figure it out

Comment: and I don't think you'are getting a valid xml right now. you 're fetching some data from DB but that's not  xml, if you make your code to return string you need to make sure that string contains valid xml formatted data. (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retruning of Array,List is not possible directly. You can create a class with array and list as member and can return object of that class.

N.B: REST cannot return Array or List

Comment: Ok so i create a class, with a String[] as a member that contains all of my info, and send it back as an Object, am I right? what type should be the best to retrieve that object? will plain text work?

Comment: You can use jackson to convert your jason output to class object or can use JaxB to convert xml to class object. Is it clear?

Comment: I finally managed to build a JSON out of an object that includes a String[] and the output is quite fine. My question now is, could I do the same without building this object? Like, directly from the String[], as it is an object itself.